Counting and Probability - Hexagon Transformations
Not including the identity transformation, the eleven transformations that preserve the regular hexagon shown are counterclockwise rotations by $60^\circ,$ $120^\circ,$ $180^\circ,$ $240^\circ$ and $300^\circ$ and reflections across the six dashed lines shown. Kristina randomly picks six transformations $T_1,$ $T_2,$ $T_3,$ $T_4$, $T_5$ and $T_6,$ with replacement, from this set of eleven. She performs these six transformations on the hexagon, in succession. The probability that the point $P$ is transformed to each of the hexagon's six vertices exactly once during this process is $\dfrac{k}{11^6}.$ What is the value of $k\,?$
My friend showed me this and I have no idea how to figure it out, but I would like to learn how to. Could someone please give me a comprehensive solution? Thanks so much in advance.


If "transformed to each of the hexagon's six vertices exactly once" means you do not count the starting position before any transformations, then it it is not difficult to answer.  What is the probability you get to a previously unvisited vertex after the first transformation? (Hint: $1$) What is the probability you get a previously unvisited vertex after the second transformation? (Hint: less than $1$) And so on.

Hint: How many transformations bring $v_i$ to $v_j$, for $i \neq j$?  (Which essentially is what Henry's comment is about.)

Doing a Google Search, this is Mathcounts 2021 State Competition
Target Round Problems 8.
